# How to convert a text field into a number field from an Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel pivot table which is dynamically generated by a third party program. One of the fields brought in is of type text, but contains a number.

I have tried setting calculated field `= VALUE('Field Name')` but it always returns zero.

Not sure if this is the best forum for this question, but none of the other SE sites seemed appropriate. Thanks so much!

Update - I am using Excel 2010

Comment: FYI, quoting from Excel help: "You do not generally need to use the VALUE function in a formula because Excel automatically converts text to numbers as necessary. This function is provided for compatibility with other spreadsheet programs."

Comment: Unfortunately the automatic conversion doesn't work either, that's the first thing I tried of course!

Answer (score 1):

You need to state which version of Excel you're using, but assuming it's a fairly recent version......

I'm not sure if your post is to be taken literally, but `Field Name` (with a space) is probably not a valid name.    Try calling it `Field_Name`.    After that, make sure a non-zero number is at location `Field_Name`.

If the above is followed, `=VALUE(Field_Name)` ....no quotes....should work (I'm staring at it right now on my machine with Excel 2007).   Any non-numeric value gives `#VALUE!`.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I am using Excel 2010. My post actually could be taken literally as the calculated field value is enclosed in single quotes for exactly this reason. Result = VALUE('Field Name'). To be clear I am working in the calculated field dialog and performing calculations using existing field names. My problem is that the data is from a third party program and I can't modify the field type =(